# Is there a way to find the Malware family from the given malware binaries?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, malware, virus, kaggle

I have a huge list of malware binaries from VirusShare website. My problem requires me to have labels of corresponding malware families to which these samples belong. Is there a way?

Answer (score 1):

Well, as far as I know, you can use VirusTotal free API ([VirusTotal API](https://www.virustotal.com/en/documentation/public-api/)) and
upload malwares to get the result of the Anti-malwares programs but they are not 
going to give you the exact family. I am not aware of any public malware family classification and I guess VT is best option you have.
(you can only send 4 request per minute I guess)